# Terraform GCP destroy single instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I have created a terraform stack with modules, and within this stack I create:

- 3 Instances (000, 001,002)
- Instance group per each Google Compute Engine (gce) instance
- Internal back-end internal load balancer (ilb)
- forwarding rule

Everything gets created fine: However as part of new image recycling we have to destroy single instance from those 3 instances created above and rebuild with new image..

My question here is that : When i am try to destroy an Instance

`destroy -force -target=module.gce_test.google_compute_instance.test_initial_follower-02`

Deletes also the `ilb` backend, forwarding rules which other instances are using...

Any ideas? Can I delete just the instance with the instance group only, no backend and forwarding rule? Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear on your VM instances.  Are these identical to each other?  Can you elaborate on the lifecycle and nature of these instances?  Don't worry about being verbose ... maybe a diagram and a link to the terraform definition?

Comment: Thanks, Yes the GCE instances are identical, just on different zone..  in respect to Life cycle, I have not set anything on instances, however i have I tried with and without ` lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true` on back-end, forwarding rule and instance group